# Domain Event pattern implementation in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I'm searching for a simple Java implementation of Udi Dahan's
Domain Events pattern and infrastructure as detailed in [this article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/).

It's pretty simple and I've implemented my own interpretation, however I'm a Java novice and don't want to be bitten by any mistakes due to inexperience with the language.

The only Java implementation I've found is in the [Jdon Framework](http://www.jdon.org/), but it's a little too heavyweight for my current in my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking for a solution to the same problem in Java EE for a while now. I looked at [Axon](http://www.axonframework.org/) and [jdon](http://www.jdon.org/) (the page doesn't really bode well either :)). Both involve Event Sourcing which I could not "sell" to my employers/customers. I wanted to have Domain Events though since I very much got used to them in .NET/C# projects. So I came up with the following...

I used a similar static DomainEvents object to give me access to a publishing mechanism without the actual implementation details leaking all over my domain model entities. So the calls something like this:

```
DomainEvents.fire(new MySampleEvent(...some params...));
```

A pattern and mechanism that is available in CDI spec are the [Events with @Observes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhic.html) that allow you to respond to certain events in normal beans with all the service available. That is similar to what I was used to when using DI frameworks like [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) where I could register generic handlers by interface. So I've got the observers (handlers, listeners, whatever you want to call them) covered. Example:

```
@Stateless
public class MySampleEventObserver {

  public void listen(@Observes MySampleEvent event) {
    ...
    doSomethingWithEvent();
  }
}
```

Now for the publishing (firing in CDI) part. Since there is no way to access CDI in entities (with good reason!) I resolved to using JNDI and [BeanManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html). I used JNDI to get the BeanManager and use it's [fireEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#fireEvent) method. To put bean manager resolving (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners)) in code:

```
public class BeanHelper {
  public static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
```

}

The final step is the DomainEvents object itself:

```
public class DomainEvents {

  private static boolean mNopMode = false;

  public static void setNopMode() {
    mNopMode = true;
  }

  public static void reset() {
    mNopMode = false;
  }

  public static <TDomainEvent> void fire(TDomainEvent event) {
    if (mNopMode) {
        return;
    }
    BeanManager manager = BeanHelper.getBeanManager();

    manager.fireEvent(event);
  }
```

}

The `setNopMode` and `reset` parts are there for testing purposes when there is no context. Manual mocking basically. Set it into NOP operation mode before unit tests and reset after them.

Works fine as a POC. Don't know if there are any serious limitations to it's use though. I leave async bus interactions and similar to the listeners implementation.

Would love any comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently looking at using Googles [Guava EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) to do something similar to the "Salvation" article you reference.

Using it similar to the "How to raise domain events" would look something like this, almost exactly the same as the article:

```
public class Customer
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MyEventBus.post(new CustomerBecamePreferred() { Customer = this });
    }
}
```

I don't know whether or not you'd consider this as an "implementation of Udi Dahan's Domain Events pattern".

It doesn't require implementing any interfaces; event handlers are marked with annotations and the class is registered with the EventBus with `MyEventBus.register(aListenerObject)`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's pretty cool-- I didn't know about Guava.  I'm really trying to keep my domain ignorant of implementation details, but I'll give Guava EventBus some thought.  Perhaps I could wrap EventBus to hide the implementation from my domain...

Comment: Yeah @HolySamosa - I'm going to wrap it when I put it in, but keep the simple `register()` and `post()` interface to it.

Comment: I assume you just going to keep the Guava Subscribe annotation in your domain model?  I like the idea of using an annotation for binding subscriptions, but I'd rather not let such an implementation detail slip into my nice, clean domain model.