# Injecting a SessionScoped Stateful bean in EntityListener

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, javabeans, cdi

I'm trying to implement some sort of auditing in a Java EE JPA (2.0) application on GlassFish 3.

I have added a `@EntityListeners` annotation on my `@MappedSuperclass` entity, the listener has the `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotation on its methods which are invoked happily at runtime.

In these methods, I'm trying to use (`@Inject`) a `@Named`, `@Stateful`, `@SessionScoped` bean (`UserSession`) in order to get current user's id. The listener class has no annotations at all.

The problem is that I can't get the `UserSession` bean injected; I always end up with a `null` value. To this time, I tried the *plain* `@Inject UserSession us;` which always injects a null value.I also tried `UserSession us = (UserSession) ctx.lookup("java:global/application/module/UserSession");` which always returns a new object (I verified the constructor call, plus the object is *empty*).

I'm pretty sure I have missed something very important regarding CDI but I can't figure out what. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a workaround, which allows me to get a reference of the `@Stateful` bean:

I created a `@Named @Singleton @Startup` bean SessionController which holds a local `HashMap<String, UserSession> sessionMap` with the references of my `@Stateful` beans:

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class SessionController {

private HashMap<String, UserSession> sessionMap;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    sessionMap = new HashMap<String, UserSession>();
}

@PreDestroy
void terminate() {
    for (UserSession us : sessionMap.values()) {
        us.logoutCleanUp(); //This is annotated as @Remove
    }
    sessionMap.clear();
}

public void addSession(String sessionId, UserSession us) {
    sessionMap.put(sessionId, us);
    System.out.println("New Session added: " + sessionId);
}

public UserSession getCurrentUserSession() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String sessionId = ((HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false)).getId();
    return sessionMap.get(sessionId);
}
```

}

I add the references from within each bean's `@PostConstruct` method:

```
public class UserSession implements Serializable {
@Inject SessionController sc;
...
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String sessionId = ((HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true)).getId();
    sc.addSession(sessionId, this);
}
```

Notice the `.getSession(true)` which is required since the Session might not be created yet. Also notice that `this` is safely passed since the `@PostConstruct` is not the constructor...

After all these, I can get the reference in my EntityListener (and any other place) like this:

```
SessionController sc = (SessionController) new InitialContext().lookup("java:module/SessionController");
    UserSession us = sc.getCurrentUserSession();
```

or like this in CDI beans

```
@Inject SessionController sc;
```

The only drawback I see is that this approach works well only for web applications (where `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is meaningful). Some of my beans (and finally my EntityListeners) are also exposed via `@javax.jws.WebService` as `@Stateless` beans. In this context (actually: absence of), my Singleton wouldn't work (haven't tested yet) since there is no *sessionId* of any kind (no session at all to be exact). I will have to use a workaround for this, possibly using SessionContext of the bean or inventing a usable *sessionId* of some sort. I will post back if I create something usable...

Answer (score 2):

EntityListners do not support CDI, at least in JPA 2.0.  It's apparently on the list of things new in [JPA 2.1](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft)

I was also surprised when I ran across this.

Comment: So there is no way to get this instance? Not even with a JNDI lookup?

Comment: We worked around this by doing some crazy ThreadLocal stuff, hopefully someone has a better suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

> To this time, I tried the plain @Inject UserSession us; which always injects a null value.

This is because in JPA 2.0 the classes are not managed by CDI, so @Inject won't work with them. These classes are managed by CDI from JPA 2.1 onward as pointed out by Steve K.

> I also tried UserSession us = (UserSession) ctx.lookup("java:global/application/module/UserSession");

You cannot lookup beans instantiated by CDI in JNDI. What you can do however, is look up the CDI BeanManager in JNDI and get your bean from the BeanManager.
It is guaranteed by the spec of CDI that you will always find the BeanManager from your application in "java:comp/BeanManager".
Here is a simplified example:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
BeanManager bm = ctx.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(UserSession.class);
Bean<?> bean = bm.resolve(beans);
CreationalContext<?> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
UserSession us = (UserSession) bm.getReference(bean, UserSession.class, ctx);
```

That will be the Bean managed by CDI, in case the session scoped UserSession instance.

My answer was based on what was proposed in [CDI injection in EntityListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This definitely seems to be solid. How is this method guaranteed to return the correct (meaning: correct session of current user/invocation) SFSB?

Comment: If you define a sessionscoped bean and look it up in this way, the cdi spec guarantees that you always get the instance belonging to the session on the executing thread. So if the CDI implementation you are using is spec. Conforming, then it will work. Most probably this also applies to SFSB too.

Comment: Very helpful! But in the last line instead of bean.getClass() it should be UserSession.class. Otherwise I am getting error WELD-001305.

Comment: Right, it should be UserSession.class or bean.getBeanClass(). getClass() is obviously wrong since it returns the type of Bean<? >. I don't know what I was thinking back in 2013 when I wrote it. :-) Thanks for the heads up, I fixed my answer.