# Injection of EJB in EntityListener via CDI fails (JPA 2.1)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, cdi, java-ee-7

I am trying to inject a `@Stateless` EJB into my EntityListner. The `@PrePresist` method of my EntityListener is invoked, but the injected EJB resolves to `null` so a NullPointerException is thrown.

```
public class MyEntityListener {

    @Inject 
    private MyService myService;  // @Stateless EJB

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(MyEntity entity) {
        final Foo foo = myService.getFoo(); // !! NPE thrown here!!
        entity.setFoo(foo);
    }
}
```

Previous questions which I found here on SO are dealing with the problem, that JPA does provide CDI only from JPA 2.1 on but not for JPA 2.0, but I am using JPA 2.1. So what else may be the problem here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
>
      <persistence-unit name="MY_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/local</jta-data-source>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
      <properties>
          <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Injection of my EJB into other session beans works fine, both with EJB inection (`@EJB`) as well as CDI injection (`@Inject`). It only fails in the EntityListner.

I am using GlassFish 4.1 with EclipseLink 2.5.2

Related questions:
[Injecting a SessionScoped Stateful bean in EntityListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368662/injecting-a-sessionscoped-stateful-bean-in-entitylistener)

Comment: What properties are you using in your persistence unit?

Comment: @Chris There is nothing special in there. I updated my quesiton and added the missing part of the persitence.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code, the behaviour is caused by this bug:

> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438105

The bug is fixed in EclipseLink 2.6.0. An update to this version solved my problem.

> http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/