# CDI how to fire events for deleted Entities

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, jboss-weld

I've created a sample application based on the JBoss Kitchensink example. This application records Entities using CDI Beans. I've found quite easy to store a new Entities using JPA + firing the Observer on the newly created Entity:

```
@Inject
private Event<MyEntity> propEventSrc;

public void put(MyEntity p){

      em.persist(p);
      propEventSrc.fire(p);
}
```

However I cannot find a way to fire the event in case the user wants to delete all records. In other words:
    public void delete(){

```
    Query query = em.createQuery("delete FROM MyEntity ");

    query.executeUpdate();

        // I need to fire an event here so that the List of MyEntities from the Producer class gets updated           
}
```

I've tried with the notifyAll() method of the propEventSrc but that does just produce Exceptions, Any idea how to solve this issue ? 
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to fire event for every entity that gets deleted, best approach would be to add [@PostRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostRemove.html) handler to entity in question and add code that fires event.

some examples http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics

you might have some problems with injecting CDI objects into EntityListener but you can workaround this(until JPA 2.1) as described in [CDI injection in EntityListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners)