# How can I use an EJB in a EntityListener?

Tags: jpa, ejb, entitylisteners

I'm designing my database and I reached the situation that an Entity itself requires to access database.

I read [Why sometimes a reference to an EntityManager inside JPA entities is needed](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/why_sometimes_the_entitymanager_in).

And I'm curious about the possibility of accessing an EJB in EntityListener.

```
public class MyEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    private void onPrePersist(final Object object) {
        // find an EJB
        // and set those required values
        // which each resides in a specific table.
    }
}
```

Is this possible or (or and) preferred?

Comment: Injecting EJBs in entity listeners has always worked for me with CDI  `@Inject` on Weld+Hibernate (WildFly 8 up to 10). I have however indeed seen users reporting this to not work, unsure about the why as they never report the exact versions of the environment used. At least I know this is known to fail in certain GlassFish versions (which uses EclipseLink instead of Hibernate).

Comment: @BalusC Are you sure you're injecting the EJB and not an instance of a class that just happens to be in the classpath

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.

- [CDI injection in EntityListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10765508/330457)
- https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft

It seems possible, according to [JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence 2.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338).

**3.5.1 Entity Listeners**

> Entity listener classes in Java EE environments support dependency injection through the Contexts and Dependency Injection API (CDI) [ 10 ] when CDI is enabled[43]. An entity listener class that makes use of CDI injection may also define lifecycle callback methods annotated with the `PostConstruct` and `PreDestroy` annotations. These methods will be invoked after injection has taken place and before the entity listener instance is destroyed respectively.
>
> The persistence provider is responsible for using the CDI SPI to create instances of the entity listener class; to perform injection upon such instances; to invoke their `PostConstruct` and `PreDestroy` methods, if any; and to dispose of the entity listener instances.