# Injection in entity listener with Quarkus

Tags: jpa, quarkus, entitylisteners

I'm trying to inject a bean into an entity listener in a Quarkus-application:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyEntityListener implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    MyService service;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void checkWrite(BaseEntity entity) {
        service.check(entity);
    }
}
```

But `service` is always `null`. Changing scope to `@SessionScoped` has no effect.

According to this 2 SO-discussions, this should be possible:

- [CDI injection in EntityListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners)
- [How can I use an EJB in a EntityListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582007/how-can-i-use-an-ejb-in-a-entitylistener)

I couldn't find any information about which JPA-version Quarkus is using, but since it is a state-of-the-art-framework I think it is JPA 2.1?

So should this be possible and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Quarkus-issue addressing this problem: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6948

Seems like Quarkus is lacking support for this feature and maybe it will be implemented in the future. There's also a workaround described.

Comment: Feature is added - tested in  Quarkus 2.4.2