# Injecting Services in Entity Listener ...?

Tags: jpa, callback, cdi, entitylisteners

Is it by any means possible to @Inject a Service-Bean (say a session bean) into an entity Listener?

Consider the following scenario as an example

Entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(BookListener.class)
public class Book {
    // fields, getters & setters
}
```

Utility class:

```
@Singleton
public class BookUtil {

    private BookRepository bookRepo;
    private List<Book> bookList;

    @Inject
    public BookUtil(BookRepository bookRepo){
        this.bookRepo = bookRepo;
        this.bookList = this.bookRepo.findAll();
    }

    public void refreshBooks(){
        this.bookList = this.bookRepo.findAll();
    }

}
```

Listener:

```
public class BookListener {

    @Inject
    BookUtil bookUtil // --> CAN THIS BE ACHIEVED?

    @PostPersist
    private void refreshCache(Book b){
        bookUtil.refreshBooks();
    }
}
```

I tried out several things I could think of but none of them successfully injected an instance of BookUtil. I could manually instantiate it, which works. But I prefer injection as then the BookRepository(inside the BookUtil) would also be injected, without me having to worry about it

Comment: From JPA spec 2.1 (chapter 3.5.1 Entity Listeners): `Entity listener classes in Java EE environments support dependency injection through the Contexts and Dependency Injection API (CDI) when CDI is enabled`. Hence you may want to add your environment information. Also, if per chance running on older version, you may be able to "cheat" the inability to do direct CDI injection via `BeanManager` which you can lookup using JNDI, Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The version of JPA we use is older than that. It's 1.10.x if i remember it right. I will then try to do the irect CDI injection via BeanManager, as updating the version is not my call :) . Thanks again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CDI injection in EntityListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners)