# @PrePersist insert query

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, hibernate-ogm

I'm in the following scenario: I have an Entity managed via JPA in mysql. Some field of the `PolyPersist`class are stored in a mysql table, a single field of that entity (`PolyPersistData`), which contains (pretty big) data is stored in MongoDB using a `@PrePersist` handler.
So, `PolyPersist` is stored in mysql table (eclipselink), but the field `PolyPersistData` in MongoDB (hibernate-ogm).

```
@Entity
public class PolyPersist {

    public PolyPersist() {
    }
    public PolyPersistData getPolyPersistData() {
        return this.polyPersistData;
    }
    public void setPolyPersistData(PolyPersistData o) {
        this.polyPersistData = o;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    @PreMergeTransient
    public void serializeData() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ClassNotFoundException, JAXBException {
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MongoEM");
        EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();
        em.persist(this.polyPersistData);
        }

    }

}
```

I know it isn't a best practice "crossing" the lifecycle of those Entities (`PolyPersist` and `PolyPersistData`).
Also, the instantiation of an EntityManager in that handler is a problem for sure (as far as I know I should limit EntityManager instances as they are heavy computationally/memory footprint speaking).
Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: EntityManagerFactory instances are heavy weight, not EntityManager instances. EntityManager instances are designed to model a unit of work and should be obtained as needed and closed and discarded when done. If you need access to a Mongo DB EMF, why not wrap it in a singleton, accessible to all calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned there are some problems with this implementation. Some of them are:

- EntityManager instantiation
- Transaction handling Synchronous and slow
- persist operation inside the handler.

I believe **the best way to do that is** to separate MySQL and MongoDB persistence completely in diferent DAO/Repositories and coordinate this from an upper layer or interceptor. The implementation will be diferent depending of with platform is being used (Java SE/EE/Spring).

I guess you don't need MongoDB at all. Removing MongoDB would make the solution simpler. You could handle the entity size problem inside MySQL using a custom tablespace or another DB level trick.

Comment: thanks, the whole aim of this project is an experiment to prove (or disprove) a boost in performance with this multiple persistence strategy. So I'm interested in any way to improve the performance of this approach. Any advices? (I'm on a Java-EE application on Tomcat, NO Spring). First of all: what's the best way to inject the MongoDB EntityManager instance in that method?

Comment: I would try to lookup a container-managed entity manager to avoid the EntityManagerFactory. It Maybe a good idea to persist data to MongoDB asynchronously using CDI events or JMS, if not overkill.

Comment: You can try to get the entity manager using JNDI. Please take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners

Comment: are those solution doable without a proper application server like Wildfly? As I said, I'm on Tomcat.

Comment: Leonardo Cruz: I like this idea, maybe there are some references or example of this kind of usage?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't implement Java EE but only a few libraries. To have a JavaEE environment you need an application server or micro-profile. You could try TomEE, it is really lightweight. It's possible to implement it without Java EE but you would need to implement a lot of stuff by yourself.

Comment: well, currently I cannot switch to another web server :/

Comment: Since it's only a test, not production code, you could instantiate only one EntityManager during startup and save it in some static attribute in your entity. It's not a robust implementation but should work.

Comment: that's the awful solution I was thinking, there's nothing better? There's no way to fire an async event (which would persist `PolyPersistData`) in my environment? Also, I guess it's not so painless to switch to TomcatEE, am I right (it's a pretty big project)?

Comment: Well, I actually never used TomEE, but looks like it's only a Tomcat distribution with Java EE libraries packed inside. So, it should not be complicated.

Comment: For me it's simpler use Wildfly, because I'm already used to it.

Comment: About the static attribute in the entity: should I keep a EntityManagerFactory or the EntityManager?

Comment: You should keep the EntityManager, because the goal is to call emfactory.createEntityManager() only once.