# Logging user info and update operations from REST / EJB service

Tags: authentication, ejb, cdi, java-ee-8

I need to log all update operations from my rest resources and store to a Database log table.

The idea is to store info like:

- logged user
- operation description about updated / saved entity
- updated fields and reference key

My application is Java EE8 compatible, it uses REST / EJB and CDI stuff.

At first I thought of dealing all this stuff on EJB side, however the exposed services don't need to have logged user on the method signature, so adding it would result on a forcing..

Is there any way to send user information, that is normally retrieved by webrequest (we use a session token model authentication) and inject through EJB ?

Comment: What do you mean by "inject through ejb"? And maybe entitylisteners help (we use them too) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765508/cdi-injection-in-entitylisteners

Comment: The entitylistener may help indeed, however the main question is: How to get logged user info from EJB, which is actually retrieved from HttpServletRequest on the REST side?

Answer (score 0):

If your session management is setup correctly, you can just inject the session context via:

```
@Resource
SessionContext sessionContext;
```

Then:

```
sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()
```

is your logged in user.

Comment: callerprincipal is anonymous, probably because the system authentication has its own mechanism

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() doesn't work as authentication mechanism does not provide it.

After some tries I found this:

**On EJB side**

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserInfo {

    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        if (this.userId != null) throw new UncheckedException("cannot infer userid twice");
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

**On REST side**

```
@Inject
UserInfo userInfo;

void userAuthenticated(...) {

    String userId = ... // get userid from access token through **WebRequest** object

    userInfo.setUserId(userId);

}
```

**Side note**

I honestly would have preferred to inject *userid* on *UserInfo* constructor but I was not allowed doing this as **WebRequest** object does not belong to EJB context

**Alternative way**

Move all the logging process to REST side by using a **Response filter**.

Example code:

```
@Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {


    @Context
    HttpServletRequest webRequest;

    @Context
    ResourceInfo resinfo;

    @Inject
    LoggingService loggingService;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) {

        final Method resourceMethod = resinfo.getResourceMethod();

        if (resourceMethod.isAnnotationPresent(Loggable.class) && containerResponseContext.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {

            // get all method's info and log to database ...

        }
    }
```